# C# web application - Browser not sending # symbol to dialer

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, mobile

I have an asp.net application and I am generating a USSD code like *777*45*345# which the user can type in or click a link to open the phone dialer. The flow works really well but I noticed on opening the dialer after clicking the button, the auto-pasted code misses the # at the end.

I don't know if it has something to do with how the data is presented to the underlying repeater; a link like this:

`<a href="tell:'<%# Eval("ussdcode")'" rel="external"></a>`

Everything is ok but just that the # doesn't come on to the dialer so it requires the user to enter the #. Not so much of a big deal but you can imagine some people will just dial in and phone will attempt to call not make a ussd dial.

Any help with how I can fix this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try HtmlEncoding the `ussdcode` ?

Comment: Thanks! Let me try that right away...